# discuss convexity of the following set?

Tags: operations-research

> discuss convexity of the following set ?
>
> $$M= \{(x,y)∈\Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2≥a^2 ,x^2+y^2≤b^2 ,x>0,y>0\}  $$

Comment: And what did you do, exactly?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Have you tried to plot the region?

Comment: i think this set is not convex 
but how can i prove that ? 
but i found a theory that the sum of two convex set is convex too

Comment: mfl's suggestion to plot the region is a very good idea.

Comment: thanks for all your efforts

Answer (score 0):

For this to be a convex set, you need to be able to draw a line $L$ between any two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in M$ such that every point $(x,y) \in L$ is also in $M$.

In this case, it's obvious that the set $M$ can only be convex if $a = 0$ and $b>0$ (Naturally, $b>a$).

If $a>0$, there will always exist a small $\epsilon > 0$ such that a line $L$ from $(a,\epsilon), (\epsilon, a)$ will always pass through your "donut hole".

Convex sets are important in discussing the uniqueness of solutions in optimization problems --which is what I'm assuming you're studying given the tags you've put on this question. Consider reading the wiki on this topic, the images on the right sidebar illustrate my point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set

Edit: Typo(s)